# Failed to build .so library

Tags: python, pip, python-3.9, .so

I am essentially running an M1 mac with Python 3.9.7 installed from python.org directly and I'm trying to build a .so library however it keeps failing showing the error below:

```
gcc -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g ./helheim_cffi.o -lpython3.9 -o ./helheim_cffi.so
ld: library not found for -lpython3.9
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 204, in link
    self.spawn(linker + ld_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 910, in spawn
    spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/spawn.py", line 91, in spawn
    raise DistutilsExecError(
distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 51, in _build
    dist.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 551, in build_extension
    self.compiler.link_shared_object(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/recompiler.py", line 1498, in my_link_shared_object
    return old_link_shared_object(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 713, in link_shared_object
    self.link(CCompiler.SHARED_OBJECT, objects,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 206, in link
    raise LinkError(msg)
distutils.errors.LinkError: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/Downloads/dist 2/examples/python/example.3/build-cffi.py", line 19, in <module>
    ffibuilder.compile(target="helheim_cffi.so", verbose=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 725, in compile
    return recompile(self, module_name, source, tmpdir=tmpdir,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/recompiler.py", line 1564, in recompile
    outputfilename = ffiplatform.compile('.', ext,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 22, in compile
    outputfilename = _build(tmpdir, ext, compiler_verbose, debug)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/ffiplatform.py", line 58, in _build
    raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
cffi.VerificationError: LinkError: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

The key part I'm looking at is: **ld: library not found for -lpython3.9**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure Python 3.9 is supported for this library you're building? Have you tried using Python 3.8 or lower?

Comment: Did you specify the location of the .so file with -L notation?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah I've tried with 3.8.2 as well, also contacted the original dev and confirmed that 3.9 is 100% working with it

Comment: @AlbinPaul the .so file is what I'm building though...

Comment: @jamesthoo I was talking about the library - python3.9

Comment: @AlbinPaul No I haven't tried that yet, would it just be the path to the IDLE such as -L/Applications/Python 3.9/IDLE.app